# Spring cloud Kafka binder without zkNodes

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Is spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes mandatory? What would happen if value is absent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is no longer required (since 2.0).

For earlier versions, we had to use Zookeeper to provision topics.

```
/**
 * Zookeeper nodes.
 * @param zkNodes the nodes.
 * @deprecated connection to zookeeper is no longer necessary
 */
@Deprecated
@DeprecatedConfigurationProperty(reason = "No longer necessary since 2.0")
public void setZkNodes(String... zkNodes) {
    this.zkNodes = zkNodes;
}
```